# R: Get sum of values for consecutive rows until certain value in a different column

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have data like this:

```
subject,item,region_num,region,region_count,time_spent
ID_2965,14,1,begin,1,2109
ID_2965,14,2,ambig,1,206
ID_2965,14,3,location,1,920
ID_2965,14,4,disamb,1,127
ID_2965,14,5,follow,1,228
ID_2965,14,6,end,1,2238
ID_2965,14,5,follow,2,62
ID_2965,14,4,disamb,2,71
ID_2965,14,2,ambig,2,89
ID_2965,14,1,begin,2,2192
ID_2965,14,2,ambig,3,83
ID_2965,14,3,location,2,133
ID_2965,14,4,disamb,3,625
ID_2965,14,5,follow,3,57
ID_2965,14,6,end,2,1079
ID_2965,34,1,begin,1,57
ID_2965,34,2,ambig,1,224
ID_2965,34,1,begin,2,2136
ID_2965,34,2,ambig,2,98
ID_2965,34,3,location,1,127
ID_2965,34,4,disamb,1,415
ID_2965,34,5,follow,1,477
ID_2965,34,6,end,1,2445
ID_2965,34,5,follow,2,70
ID_2965,34,3,location,2,72
ID_2965,34,1,begin,3,3160
ID_2965,34,2,ambig,3,96
ID_2965,34,4,disamb,2,85
ID_2965,34,5,follow,3,213
ID_2965,34,6,end,2,482
ID_2965,34,5,follow,4,100
ID_2965,34,6,end,3,157
```

What I would need is to create a new column called "gopast" through three steps:

1. For each row find all **subsequent rows** which have lower or equal region_num values than this given row for the given subject and item **until the first subsequent row with a higher region_num value** than the given region_num value.
2. For those rows where there are no subsequent rows which have lower region_num values, the gopast value should be equal to time_spent.
3. For those rows where there are immediately subsequent rows which have lower or equal region_num values, sum the time_spent for the given row and all these subsequent rows.
4. The gopast variable is only relevant to region_count==1.

In other words, the resulting data should look like this:

```
subject,item,region_num,region,region_count,time_spent,gopast
ID_2965,14,1,begin,1,2109,2109
ID_2965,14,2,ambig,1,206,206
ID_2965,14,3,location,1,920,920
ID_2965,14,4,disamb,1,127,127
ID_2965,14,5,follow,1,228,228
ID_2965,14,6,end,1,2238,6629
ID_2965,14,5,follow,2,62,NA
ID_2965,14,4,disamb,2,71,NA
ID_2965,14,2,ambig,2,89,NA
ID_2965,14,1,begin,2,2192,NA
ID_2965,14,2,ambig,3,83,NA
ID_2965,14,3,location,2,133,NA
ID_2965,14,4,disamb,3,625,NA
ID_2965,14,5,follow,3,57,NA
ID_2965,14,6,end,2,1079,NA
ID_2965,34,1,begin,1,57,57
ID_2965,34,2,ambig,1,224,2458
ID_2965,34,1,begin,2,2136,NA
ID_2965,34,2,ambig,2,98,NA
ID_2965,34,3,location,1,127,127
ID_2965,34,4,disamb,1,415,415
ID_2965,34,5,follow,1,477,477
ID_2965,34,6,end,1,2445,6880
ID_2965,34,5,follow,2,70,NA
ID_2965,34,3,location,2,72,NA
ID_2965,34,1,begin,3,3160,NA
ID_2965,34,2,ambig,3,96,NA
ID_2965,34,4,disamb,2,85,NA
ID_2965,34,5,follow,3,213,NA
ID_2965,34,6,end,2,482,NA
ID_2965,34,5,follow,4,100,NA
ID_2965,34,6,end,3,157,NA
```

Any idea how to do it? I tried multiple things in R and also searched for a solution here and elsewhere, but I was unsuccessful.

The best thing I was able to come up with was this after I included the rowN variable specifying the row number:

```
add_gopast <- function(df) {
  df$gopast <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    time_spent <- df$time_spent[i]
    region_num <- df$region_num[i]
    region <- df$region[i]
    lower_region_rows <- which(df$rowN > df$rowN[i] & df$region_num <= region_num & df$subject == df$subject[i] & df$item == df$item[i]& df$region_count >= df$region_count[i])
    if (length(lower_region_rows) > 0) {
      if (df$regout[i] == 0) {
        gopast_value <- time_spent
      } else if (df$regout[i] == 1) {
        gopast_value <- time_spent + sum(df$time_spent[lower_region_rows])
      }
      df$gopast[i] <- gopast_value
    } else {
      df$gopast[i] <- time_spent
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

The problem is that it does not stop the summation when the first subsequent row with a higher region_num value than the given region_num value is encountered...

Comment: Are you able to run `dput()` on the two datasets your provide above (that will let others easily place those data objects in their own R sessions, hopefully getting more responses)

Answer (score 1):

1. Group your data by 'subject' and 'item' with `group_by`;
2. For each group, create a variable that indicates if the difference of the next 'region_num' is positive, and `cumsum` it to create another grouping variable;
3. If `region_count != 1`, the 'gopast' isn't relevant and should simply be 'time_spent' (i'm assuming that that's what you meant with `df$regout[i] == 0`). Otherwise, get the the cumulative mean with an inverse order with `rev() %>% cummean() %>% rev()`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(subject, item) %>%
  group_by(region_num_diff = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(region_num) > 0)), .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(gopast = case_when(region_count == 1 ~ time_spent %>% rev() %>% cummean() %>% rev(),
                            TRUE ~ time_spent))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 32 × 8
# Groups:   subject, item, region_num_diff [23]
   subject  item region_num region   region_count time_spent region_num_diff gopast
   <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>      <dbl>           <int>  <dbl>
 1 ID_2965    14          1 begin               1       2109               1  2109 
 2 ID_2965    14          2 ambig               1        206               2   206 
 3 ID_2965    14          3 location            1        920               3   920 
 4 ID_2965    14          4 disamb              1        127               4   127 
 5 ID_2965    14          5 follow              1        228               5   228 
 6 ID_2965    14          6 end                 1       2238               6   930.
 7 ID_2965    14          5 follow              2         62               6    62 
 8 ID_2965    14          4 disamb              2         71               6    71 
 9 ID_2965    14          2 ambig               2         89               6    89 
10 ID_2965    14          1 begin               2       2192               6  2192 
# … with 22 more rows
```